# Modal popup for valueBox with shinyjs and flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard, shinyjs

I'm trying to trigger a popup message for a valueBox in flexdashboard using shinyjs.  There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722207/shiny-trigger-a-popup-by-clicking-a-valuebox) but it doesn't work with flexdashboard.

The flexdashboard is created using an RMarkdown file.

````
---
title: "Test valuebox"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)

onclick('valbox', showModal(modalDialog(
    title = "message",
    "This is an important message!"
  )))
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

```{r ui}
sliderInput('valsel', 'Select number:', min = 0, max = 10, value = 5)
```

Column 
-------------------------------------

###   

```{r}

output$valbox <- renderValueBox(flexdashboard::valueBox(input$valsel, "selected"))

valueBoxOutput('valbox')
```
````

I've inspected the HTML created by the app and the id for the value box is indeed 'valbox'. I tried creating a unique id with  tags, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you trying to generate the popup only when the program initiates, or when a certain value is selected?

Comment: Popup should be generated when the valueBox is clicked by the user.

Comment: Hi @fawda123, did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Dwight no, haven't figured this out.